# Styling works as intended in 'responsive design mode' but breaks in small desktop window

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design, responsive

I have an issue which only occurs in small desktop browser windows. The 'responsive design mode' shows the content as intended, however if I resize my browser to the same dimensions in a normal browser window the view is changed.

More specifically I did a 'hidden scroll bar css trick' roughly just the css:

```
padding-right: 17px;
box-sizing: content-box;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 100%;
```

In the 'responsive design mode' the view looks roughly like this:

[image: intended view]

In a small browser window with the same size the view looks like this:

[image: broken view]

This is fixable by adjusting the width to 102%, but the question is:

How do I target only small browsers and not mobile devices ? Perhaps even better, what 'hide scroll bar' css trick could avoid this issue on small desktop browsers ?

I prefer a sass only solution, but jquery options could be a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include `overflow-y: auto;` instead of `overflow-y: scroll;`. As, `overflow-y` with `scroll` property adds scroll bar no matter what is the situation. But on the other hand, `overflow-y` with `auto` adds scroll when content is exceeding the given limit.